Find a fundamental unit by using the continued fraction

Definition: An irrational number $\theta>1$ is said to be reduced if $-\frac{1}{\overline{\theta}}>1$ where ${\overline{\theta}}$ denotes the conjugate of $\theta$.


Theorem: Let $D$ be the discriminant of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$(not necessarily square-free) and let $\theta$ be a reduced element of $K$ having discriminant $D$, and let $[\overline{a_1,\ldots,a_n}]$ be the continued fraction expansion of $\theta$ with period $k$. Then the fundamental unit of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is $$\epsilon=q_{k-1}+q_k\theta$$

Example: Consider $\mathbb{Q}{(\sqrt{19})}$. We have $$\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{19}-4}=[\overline{2,1,3,1,2,8}]$$ and $$(q_{-1},q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4,q_5,q_6)=(1,0,1,1,4,5,14,117)$$Thus, the fundamental unit $\epsilon$ is$$q_5+q_6\theta=14+117\frac{1}{\sqrt{19}-4}$$
$Question:$ What is the discriminant of one element here? I only know how to define the discriminant under a basis.
In the example, I think this $\theta$ is not reduced since the conjugation of $\theta$ is itself and it is positive, then take the minus, it cannot be greater than $1$. What's wrong here?
Thank you for your help.
$\textbf{Edit}:$ Let $\alpha_1=\theta$ and $a_1=[\theta]$(the greatest integer function). If $\alpha_1 \notin \mathbb{Z}$, continue inductively by setting $$\alpha_{n+1}=\frac{1}{\alpha_n-a_n}, a_{n+1}=[\alpha_{n+1}]$$
Then define s sequence $P_0,P_1,\ldots$: $$P_0=\begin{pmatrix} p_0 & p_{-1}\\ q_0 & q_{-1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}, P_n=\begin{pmatrix} p_n & p_{n-1}\\ q_n & q_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 &1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\ldots\begin{pmatrix} a_n & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
One can also show that $p_{n+1}=a_{n+1}p_{n}+p_{n-1}, q_{n+1}=a_{n+1}q_n+q_{n-1}.$

A few points are not entirely clear to me: First, what do you mean by $\overline{\theta}$? Do you already suppose some ambient quadratic field with a unique nontrivial $\Bbb{Q}$-linear automorphism?

Second, is the $d$ in $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ assumed to be a squarefree positive integer, preferably $d\neq1$?

Third, what do you mean by a 'reduced element'? (I see now that you 'define' this above, so this should be answered once my first question is answered)

Fourth, what do you mean by the discriminant of $\theta$? Is that the discriminant of the $\Bbb{Q}$-linear map induced on $K$ by multiplication by $\theta$?

Fifth, what are the $q_k$ in $\epsilon=q_{k-1}+q_k\theta$?

@Servaes Thank you for your comment. Hope it's fine now. But for the fourth one, there is no explanation in the note.

What's the source of that theorem? I have a guess as to what the discriminant should mean (which makes the calculation work), but it would be helpful to see the reference to confirm.

@anankElpis Here, page 84, Theorem 3,36.

First the easy part: The conjugation in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$ for $d>0$ refers not to complex conjugation, but to the Galois action $$\overline{a+b\sqrt d}:=a-b\sqrt d.$$ With this notion, it is easy to see that the given $\theta$ is reduced: $-\frac1{\overline\theta}=4+\sqrt{19}>1$.

The discriminant of an element of $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$ is, as far as I know, not a standard notion. The notes you linked refer to H. Koch, "Number Theory: Algebraic Numbers and Functions". In section 9.1, the author simply defines for $\gamma\in K$ that $D(\gamma)=b^2-4ac$, where $ax^2+bx+c$ is the reduced quadratic polynomial with $\gamma$ as a zero.
One can relate this to the discriminant of orders in $\mathcal O_K$ as follows: We have $a\gamma\in\mathcal O_K$, as it is a zero of the integral polynomial $x^2+bx+ac$. Define the order $O:=(1,a\gamma)\subset\mathcal O_K$, then the discriminant of this order can be computed via the standard definition as $$D(O)=\det\begin{pmatrix}1&\overline 1\\a\gamma&\overline{a\gamma}\end{pmatrix}^2=a^2(\gamma-\bar\gamma)^2=b^2-4ac,$$ since the distance of the zeroes of $ax^2+bx+c$ is exactly $\frac1a\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ by the quadratic formula. Therefore, you could also define more intrinsically $$D(\gamma)=D(\gamma\mathcal O_K\cap\mathcal O_K).$$

In the given example, the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ is $3x^2-8x-1$, hence $D(\theta)=8^2+4\cdot3=4\cdot19$, as expected. Alternatively, $\theta\mathbb Z[\sqrt{19}]\cap\mathbb Z[\sqrt{19}]=(1,4+\sqrt{19})$, hence $$D(\theta)=D(1,4+\sqrt{19})=\det\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\4+\sqrt{19}&4-\sqrt{19}\end{pmatrix}^2=4\cdot19,$$ yielding the same result.
